# How to get the latest date, billing number and stock by using two criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am facing a problem where I need to use "material and batch number" at the same time in order get the latest GI date and billing number from the raw data that I pull from the system. The Raw data has hundred to thousand lines of material, batch number, GI date and billing number. Same materials could have different batch numbers, GI dates or billing numbers.

Instead of manually filtering and searching, is there any formula I can use?

[image: used material and batch to get latest date and billing number]

Comment: Are your dates real dates? The alignment in row 14 is different, so I wonder. Is the green table sorted by GI Date or is that just coincidence?

Comment: It will help if your screenshot names match the names in your description. You mention material which I assume matches Raw Data Code. I think you'll run into issues later... I think you should invest in learning Access to make a query out of it. You'll be able to automate getting the missing data easily after you set it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date column in the "green" table contains real dates, not text that looks like a date, then you can use this approach:

```
C2  =MAX(IF(($A$7:$A$14=A2)*($B$7:$B$14=B2),$C$7:$C$14))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter. That will put curly braces around the formula.

```
D2  =INDEX($D$7:$D$14,MATCH(B2&C2,INDEX($B$7:$B$14&$C$7:$C$14,0),0))
E2  =VLOOKUP(D2,$A$18:$C$23,3,0)
```

Edit after your comments and new screenshots:

The formula in E2 changes to

```
=INDEX($C$18:$C$22,MATCH(D2&B2,INDEX($A$18:$A$22&$B$18:$B$22,0),0))
```

See screenshot with sample setup and working formulas.

[image]

If you need any more clarification, please DO NOT post more screenshots. Create an Excel workbook with sample data and use a file sharing service, post a link.

Comment: Thanks Teylyn and Leviathan for the help. As referring to Teylyn , I have tried your way for GI date at "C2" but it prompt out formula contains error. Any how, I realize that batch number only tag with one material code , it would not tag with different material code. Therefore I lookup the GI date by batch number which is C2 = MAX(IF(B7:B14=B2,C7:C14)).

Comment: D2 , i follow the formula i manage to get the billing number for the batch number and GI date. However, "E2" stock balance I just realize my table not clear. My data have few line of same billing number "8272001755" but with Different batch number "C174188C", "C23548C","D128654F". How can i get the quantity of stock for the exactly billing number and batch number?

Comment: The best way to get a working suggestion is to post a data sample that really reflects your data. Following wordy descriptions about data does not help. Update your question with a more accurate data sample, then add a comment here.

Comment: You are correct. I have edited the question and sample data on top.

Comment: I responded to the new screenshots.

Comment: I have see the "link" button to click but not sure how to use it. Therefore, I only click Image button to show my question and table. I have try to search in help center but seem like doesn't useful to me. Could you mind to teach me how to put link?

Comment: You will need more reputation before you can post a link. But just post the URL of the link as text in your question and people who know how links work can use it.